# Ektorp querying performance against CouchDB is 4x slower when initiating the request from a remote host

Tags: couchdb, httpclient, ektorp

I have a Spring MVC app running under Jetty. It connects to a CouchDB instance on the same host using Ektorp. 
In this scenario, once the Web API request comes into Jetty, I don't have any code that connects to anything not on the localhost of where the Jetty instance is running. This is an important point for later.

I have debug statements in Jetty to show me the performance of various components of my app, including the performance of querying my CouchDB database.

Scenario 1: When I initiate the API request from localhost, i.e. I use Chrome to go to http://localhost:8080/, my debug statements indicate a CouchDB peformance of X. 
Scenario 2: When I initiate the exact same API request from a remote host, i.e. I use Chrome to go to http://:8080/, my debug statements indicate a CouchDB performance of 4X.

It looks like something is causing the connection to CouchDB to be much slower in scenario 2 than scenario 1. That doesn't seem to make sense, since once the request comes into my app, regardless of where it came from, I don't have any code in the application that establishes the connection to CouchDB differently based on where the initial API request came from. As a matter of fact, I have nothing that establishes the connection to CouchDB differently based on anything.
It's always the same connection (from the application's perspective), and I have been able to reproduce this issue 100% of the time with a Jetty restart in between scenario 1 and 2, so it does not seem to be related to caching either.

I've gone fairly deep into StdCouchDbConnector and StdHttpClient to try to figure out if anything is different in these two scenarios, but cannot see anything different.

I have added timers around the executeRequest(HttpUriRequest request, boolean useBackend) call in StdHttpClient to confirm this is where the delay is happening and it is. The time difference between Scenario 1 and 2 is several fold on client.execute(), which basically uses the Apache HttpClient to connect to CouchDB.

I have also tried always using the "backend" HttpClient in StdHttpClient, just to take Apache HTTP caching out of the equation, and I've gotten the same results as Scenarios 1 and 2.

Has anyone run into this issue before, or does anyone have any idea what may be happening here? I have gone all the way down to the org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirectory to try to see if anything was different between scenarios 1 and 2, but couldn't find anything ...

A couple of additional notes:

a. I'm currently constrained to a Windows environment in EC2, so instances are virtualized. 
b. Scenarios 1 and 2 give the same response time when the underlying instance is not virtualized. But see a - I have to be on AWS. 
c. I can also reproduce similar 4X slower performance as in scenario 2 with this third scenario: instead of making the localhost:8080/ using Chrome, I make it using Postman, which is a Chrome application. Using Postman from the Jetty instance itself, I can reproduce the 4X slower times.

The only difference I see in c. above is that the request headers in Chrome's developer tools indicate a Remote Address of [::1]:8080. I don't have any way to set that through Postman, so I don't know if that's the difference maker. And if it were, first I wouldn't understand why. And second, I'm not sure what I could do about it, since I can't control how every single client is going to connect to my API.

All theories, questions, ideas welcome. Thanks in advance!